# Is it safe to use one method for running similar Stored Procedures, passing the StoredProcedure name as a method parameter

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

OK, so I understand all about the importance of using SqlParameters, and this question may seem a little dumb, but I'm not entirely sure on the answer and want to make sure I make the right decision.

Consider this simple c# method:

```
public static void MakeLinks (int tableOneId, List<int> tableTwoIds, string storedProcedureName)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(<connection string>))
    {
        // Code Omitted

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // SqlParameterCollection code omitted

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a large number of methods that link rows in various combinations of tables.  In each one, there is a single Id for 'TableOne' and a collection of Ids for 'TableTwo'.  Each combination has a relevant StoredProcedure in the database and the .NET  code is extremely repetitive.  I'm therefore considering using the above approach, updating all StoredProcedure parameter names to be the same (e.g. @Id rather than "@tableOneId", "@tableTwoId" etc.) and then simply passing the name of the StoredProcedure to the method and creating the command string as such:

```
string commandString = String.Format("[DatabaseName].[dbo].{0}", storedProcedureName);
```

My question is therefore, Is this still safe, or is there a better way to handle / do this?

Your thoughts and advice are much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is safe as long as the CommandType is "StoredProcedure".

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Great, thank you for such a fast response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the names of your stored-procedure parameters makes it no more, or less safe.  One might conceivably argue that someone who has gained access to your database might notice the pattern - but then the astute will realise that if an attacker has got that kind of access to your database then you're screwed anyway.

If you can make your code more re-usable by making the parameter names generic - then go for it, I say.  It also semi-documents that these stored procedures perform the same *kind* of function and I wish more stored-procedures that I have had the misfortune of coming across had *some* kind of naming convention that could be relied upon!

Comment: great, thank you for such a fast response.  I really appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to use one method for running similar Stored Procedures,
>   passing the StoredProcedure name as a method parameter

**Yes**

Looks like you have multiple procedures with similar working only differing in their names. There shouldn't be any problem *(like SQL Injection)* by passing procedure name to C# method.

Comment: Thank you also for such a fast response.  I feel much better making the move with three for's and zero against's!!